# Recommendation for setting minimal hot cache for least accessed tables

Tags: azure-data-explorer

Is it fine to set hot cache as 0s (or very minimal) if we don't query certain table usually ? I am asking this because I was told once that as a rule of thumb hot cache has to be minimum 1 day regardless of access frequency because hot cache is used during rebuild/merge process and if data to be merged is not found hot cache during the merge, it's accessed from cold storage (Azure blob) causing throttling. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

while it's technically possible to set `0s` as the caching period, doing so may harm the efficiency of background processes such as merging data shards (e.g. due to having to read artifacts from blob storage instead of from the local cache).

it's recommended that you set the caching policy to at least several hours (e.g. `6h`) in order to avoid the aforementioned potential impact.

plus, if the table is frequently queried - consider setting the caching period to match the timespan that is queried the most, to improve overall performance.